# ArcMap Int tool seems to cut max value in half?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst

I have ran into an issue with the ArcMap tools in both 3D Analyst and Spatial Analyst.

I convert an elevation grid from meters to centimeters by using the Times tool with a constant of 100. Works exactly as expected and gives correct values.

When I use the Int tool to convert the floating point numbers to integers, the max value gets cut in half. The max goes from ~23k to 12k.

Here is a picture of the elevation grid at the start (top), after Times (bottom) and then Int (middle):

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried recalculating the Statistics on the output of the Int tool?

Comment: ... Thanks... 

Someone else was over here and helping me yesterday. He was baffled and tried running Calculate Statistics from ArcMap, but it failed.

I just ran it from ArcCatalog... and now the values are right...